# Tool to parse website and search specifc words

Tags: keywords, search, tools, application

Is there a tool that could help to parse a website and look for a specific word?

I've searched using google but haven't found something that would be suitable for the needs I have.

Not just the page I'm on, for this I could simply use the CTRL+F shortcut, but the entire website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) is probably the best tool for this, but be aware that the pro version costs £99 per year (which is usually worth it if you do this kind of thing often). Normally it'll just crawl the site you specify, and record details like title tags, meta robots, etc. But you can add user-defined filters, so that it looks for a particular word in the source code of each page, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**ParseHub**](https://www.parsehub.com/) is what you need, I use that tool to extract every information that I like from websites.